# Rotate around a point with a 3x3 matrix and a translation vector

Tags: c++, opengl, linear-algebra, opengl-3

I have a 3x3 matrix in openGL format and a translation vector. I get confused when rotating around a point because my rotate function does not consider translation.

For rotating I assumed I could simply change the 3x3 matrix into a quaternion, rotate it and then change it back. This does not work when rotating about anything other than the objects current position.

The normal procedure for 4x4 matrcies is:

translate point by `-(point - position)`

rotate

translate point by `(point - position)`

Optional advice:

Bullet physics uses this format and that is why I was considering using their data format to store transformations. I do eventually have to convert to a 4x4 matrix to do projection, but that does not matter all that much. Bullet's format is attractive because it removes the useless shear data. Is it worth the bother to keep transformations in bullet format or no?

Comment: Bullet Vectors actually take up more space, but are simpler than Eigen so I am still going to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Came up with one. Just do matrix math. Create the rotation matrix manually or from a quaternion and then just multiply them. Bullet does this for you but i'll show what bullet does internally too.

*psuedo code

```
void Transform::rotateAroundPoint(axis, angle, point)
{
Matrix3x3 mat = createMatrixFromQuaternion(axis, angle);
Transform rotateTransform;
trans.basis = mat; // <- 3x3 matrix
trans.origin = Vector3(0,0,0); // <- Translation vector

// "this" is a pointer to the transform being edited since I decided to write 
// this as a member function.

Vector3 pos = this->origin;
this->origin = this->origin - point; 
(*this) = rotateTransform * (*this);
this->origin = this->origin + point;
}

// Internally bullet does basically this
resultTransform.basis = t1.basis * t2.basis;
resultTransform.origin = t1.basis * t2.origin + t1.origin;
```

I have not tested the code yet. I am a little bit terrified that it may suffer from gimbal lock so in my actual code I am probably going to just do quaternion math when i have to multiply 2 basis matricies.